# Understanding pcap packet header

Tags: c, networking, pcap

Could someone explain me how **pcap packet header** are used in C? 
I can't find any clear explanation on how it is structured and used.

In fact, the thing is I don't understand how we use the pcap library `#include <pcap.h>`

Indeed, I need to use a 
`struct pcap_pkthdr *header` but I can't figure out how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pcap defines a header for each packet. Together with the pcap file header the packet header will make you be able to understand the data in the pcap dump.

```
struct pcap_file_header {
        bpf_u_int32 magic;
        u_short version_major;
        u_short version_minor;
        bpf_int32 thiszone; /* gmt to local correction */
        bpf_u_int32 sigfigs;    /* accuracy of timestamps */
        bpf_u_int32 snaplen;    /* max length saved portion of each pkt */
        bpf_u_int32 linktype;   /* data link type (LINKTYPE_*) */
};

struct pcap_pkthdr {
        struct timeval ts;      /* time stamp */
        bpf_u_int32 caplen;     /* length of portion present */
        bpf_u_int32 len;        /* length this packet (off wire) */
};
```

So first you will have the file header and then all the captured packets after that.
In C you can read 24 bytes of the pcap dump and then map these bytes to the pcap file header structure. After this you can start with reading all the different packets. Note that there are different versions of pcap and what I wrote here does not apply on every pcap dump.